# Conditional reset of data in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I am looking for an efficient way (without looping/iteration, if possible) of getting my output below using inputs a and b. a is an array with random numbers and b is and array which defines reset points.

```
a = pd.DataFrame([2, 5, 4, 1, 6, 6, 4, 7])
b = pd.DataFrame([1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0])
```

output:

```
[2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4]
```

Comment: Aside: if `a` and `b` are like arrays, they probably make sense as `Series` objects rather than `DataFrame` objects.

Comment: Yes, they actually are Time Series. But they are part of a dataframe with multiple such columns. b actually is a result of comparision of a particular column with it's preceding number to check certain condition. The actual problem was a bit complicated so I tried to keep my question to the point where I was stuck, rest I was able to figue out. But yes for a question as simple as above it would make more sense as Series.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply index with `b` as a boolean array, and then fill the `NaN` values, in this case with a forward fill (`ffill` method):

```
a[b.astype(bool)].fillna(method='ffill')
```

For `fillna` docs, see: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html